# integrate wso2ESB with CAS

Tags: cas, wso2-esb

I am newer for wso2. Now i want to integrate wso2ESB with CAS, and i know ESB runs on top of tomcat.  i configure org.wso2.carbon.ui/4.1.0/src/main/resources/web/ESB-INF/web.xml as follows.It seems that CAS filters don't work,but the same configuration work well on Common web applications. Anyone can give me some advice? 
   Thanks in advance.

```
 <filter >
        <filter-name >CAS Single Sign Out Filter </filter-name >
       <filter-class >org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter </filter-class >
 </filter >

 <filter >
        <filter-name >CAS Authentication Filter </filter-name >
       <filter-class >org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter </filter-class >
        <init-param >
             <param-name >casServerLoginUrl </param-name >
             <param-value >http://10.21.3.36:8080/cas/login </param-value >
        </init-param >
        <init-param >
             <param-name >serverName </param-name >
             <param-value >https://localhost:9443 </param-value >
        </init-param >
        <init-param >
             <param-name >renew </param-name >
             <param-value >false </param-value >
        </init-param >
        <init-param >
             <param-name >gateway </param-name >
             <param-value >false </param-value >
        </init-param >
 </filter >
 <filter >
        <filter-name >CAS Validation Filter </filter-name >
       <filter-class >org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter </filter-class >
        <init-param >
             <param-name >casServerUrlPrefix </param-name >
             <param-value >http://10.21.3.36:8080/cas/ </param-value >
        </init-param >
        <init-param >
             <param-name >serverName </param-name >
             <param-value >https://localhost:9443 </param-value >
        </init-param >
 </filter >

 <filter >
        <filter-name >CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
       <filter-class >org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter </filter-class >
 </filter >

 <filter >
        <filter-name >CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
       <filter-class >org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter </filter-class >
 </filter >

 <!-- ************************* -->

 <filter-mapping >
        <filter-name >CAS Single Sign Out Filter </filter-name >
        <url-pattern >/* </url-pattern >
 </filter-mapping >

 <filter-mapping >
        <filter-name >CAS Authentication Filter </filter-name >
        <url-pattern >/carbon/* </url-pattern >
 </filter-mapping >

 <filter-mapping >
        <filter-name >CAS Validation Filter </filter-name >
        <url-pattern >/* </url-pattern >
 </filter-mapping >

 <filter-mapping >
        <filter-name >CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern >/* </url-pattern >
 </filter-mapping >

 <filter-mapping >
        <filter-name >CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern >/* </url-pattern >
 </filter-mapping >

 <!-- *********************** -->

 <listener >
       <listener-class >org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener </listener-class >
 </listener >

 <!-- *********************** -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your filters in /repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/META-INF/context.xml to reflect your changes